# VBA crashes on PC. Works on Mac

Tags: vba, excel

This Sub works on Mac. But not on PC. I've commented the affected line.
Any ideas?

```
Sub addEmptyProjectRow()

    Call unProtectAll

    Dim projectsTable As ListObject
    Set projectsTable = Worksheets("Projects").ListObjects("PROJECTS_TABLE")

    projectsTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    projectsTable.ListRows.Add (1)
    projectsTable.Range(2, projectsTable.ListColumns("Lead").Index).Value = Application.username

    ' This line produces the error on PC
    projectsTable.Range(2, 1).Select

    Call protectAll

End Sub
```

un/ProtectAll looks like this

```
Public Function protectAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowSorting:=True
        Next ws
End Function

Public Function unProtectAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Unprotect
        Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: (a) What error do you get? (b) Is "Projects" the active worksheet when the code is run?  (c) Does your `unProtectAll` procedure change the active worksheet? (d) You have a syntax error (due to extra `)`) in the line saying `projectsTable.ListColumns("Lead").Index).Value = Application.username`

Comment: Have you.... rebooted or tried uninstall/reinstalling Office? I hate to state the `helpdesk` answer but it has truly solved my problems on more than one occasion. If it is truly freezing and crashing Word with no message, I would try both.

Comment: @GibralterTop ..it's Excel ;-)  but yeah, Word is excellent for crashing all by itself!

Comment: $100 the `Projects` sheet happens to be active when the sub runs on a Mac, and another sheet happens to be active when the sub runs on PC. You can't `.Select` a range that isn't on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Note to self: always read @YowE3K's comments first.

Comment: The "Lead )" syntax error was mistake during the a copy and paste procedure to stackoverflow. Code updated.

Comment: I've added the un/protectAll functions to the code

Comment: I just get an "error 1004". The select-method… the range object"

Comment: Maybe the Un/protectAll functions are the problem. Actually I just recognized some flashing of the screen whenever the method runs?! Does the script quickly open alle sheets to unprotect?!

Comment: @Mat'sMug ... DOH!

Comment: @fabian the linked question contains your answer. For the record Mac/Windows has nothing to do with it.